# Class.forName("org.MyClass") and MyClass.class differences

Tags: java, reflection

`Class.forName("org.MyClass")` and `MyClass.class` both require class name. So, what does it mean when we say `Class.forName("org.MyClass")` is used when we don't know the name of the class at compile time and `MyClass.class` is used when we know the name of the class?

How are these different from `obj.getClass()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself: when you use `MyClass.class`, then the compiler needs to know what `MyClass` is, so you'll need to have `MyClass` in your classpath at compile time; whereas when you use `Class.forName("org.MyClass")`, the class does not need to be in the classpath at compile time - only at runtime.

This is used for example for JDBC drivers. You write your code to use the JDBC API, but you don't need to specify at compile time which JDBC driver you're going to use. This also allows you to switch to another JDBC driver without recompiling your own code.

`obj.getClass()` gets the `Class` object for `obj`.

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass.class` is generally known at compile time to be a given class.

`obj.getClass()` is used when an object is known but not its class, or if the object is a refiable generic type, to get a class.

`Class.forName("org.YourClass")` is needed if you know the name of the class (i.e. the name was passed over the network or was otherwise obtained as a string) without an instance of the class, or the class's identity known at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("org.MyClass") equal to MyClass

MyClass.class equal to Class<MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

with `MyClass.class` you get the class at compile-time.

and with `Class.forName("org.MyClass")` at runtime.

Your normaly pass a value to Class#forName and don't hardcode the String. If it's hard-coded, uses `.class`

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass.class`:

- Can be assigned to `Class<MyClass>`, hence `newInstance()` returns `MyClass`.
- Compilation fails if the class doesn't exist in the classpath.
- Doesn't throw any checked exceptions.

`Class.forName("org.MyClass")`:

- Cannot be assigned to `Class<MyClass>`, but `Class<?>` instead, hence `newInstance()` returns `Object`.
- Compilation successes even if the class doesn't exist in the classpath.
- Throws the checked exception `ClassNotFoundException` which needs to be handled.